# Ubuntu 15.04 freezing completely

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound, 15.04, freeze

So I dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 15.04 and whenever I boot up Ubuntu, after around 15 minutes or so, it will just freeze and i'll be able to hear the sounds and stuff but after another minutes it completely freezes and I can't switch through tty or anything and I have to restart my computer and just repeat the same thing over again. It has gotten to the point where I just stay on windows all the time even though I really want to use Ubuntu. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04LTS. This my solve alot of your "bugs" and issues that you are having with 15.04. However a fresh install of 14.04 is recommended so you would lose any data saved on the current system.